# Why doesn't Mathematica simplify a square root of an expression that equals a square of a positive real?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When I try and simplify this expression:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[Sqrt[ x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] ], (x | y) \[Element] Reals]
Out[1]= Sqrt[x^2 + 2 y (y + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])]
```

it does not simplify properly.
However, *Mathematica* knows it equals a simpler expression:

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[ Sqrt[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] ] == Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + y, (x | y) \[Element] Reals]
Out[2]= True
```

Why doesn't *Mathematica* simplify this expression, and how can I make it do it anyway, even if the expression is part of a larger expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly because the second simplification request is much easier than the first. Consider:

[image]

Also, the second `FullSimplify` can be done by `Simplify`. Not surprising since all MMA has to do is square both sides.

edit: Perhaps this will suggest an approach:

[image]

Comment: This is true, but why is the first simplification so hard that _Mathematica_ doesn't find it? And is there a way to make it find it?

Comment: @Joe Why is it so important to you that `FullSimplify` be able to carry out this simplification? Why can't you just apply your knowledge of the equality of the two expressions directly to whatever work you are doing?

Comment: Since I am trying to simplify a very long expression that contains multiple versions of the expression I'm asking about, and I don't want to go through my long expression manually.

Comment: Great idea! It can be a bit simplified by using just one replacement rule: `x_^2 + 2 y_^2 + 2 y_ Sqrt[x_^2 + y_^2] -> (Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + y)^2`.

Answer (score 7):

Change to polar coordinates, {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]}:

```
FullSimplify[ Sqrt[2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] + x^2 + 2y^2] /. 
 {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]}, r > 0 && 0 < t< 2Pi]

r (Sin[t] + 1)
```

This should simplify your long expression ...

Comment: Nice! Then I just add `/.{r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], t -> ArcTan[x, y]}` and simplify again and I have the simplified expression in my original variables. On the other hand, I have this expression appearing multiple times with different variables instead of `x` and `y`, and I'm not sure if your approach can be generalized to such a case.

Comment: Awesome tip! I had trouble that Mathematica wouldn't simplify expressions with complex numbers properly, and would take ages to handle them. Now I just write them in polar co-ordinates, and add assumptions that the real and imaginary parts are real, which increases the performance immensely.

Answer (score 2):

You might do this:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] /. x^2 -> u^2 - y^2, {u > 0, y > 0}] /. u -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

The result is here: `y + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]`

I required that both `u` and `y` are positive. If they are not:

```
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] /.x^2 -> u^2 - y^2, {u < 0, y < 0}] /. u -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

You get another result: `Abs[-y + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == Expand[(Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b])^2]
(*x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == a + 2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] + b*)

Solve[{a + b == x^2 + 2 y^2, 2 Sqrt[a b] == 2 y Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}, {a, b}, Reals]
Simplify[Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[b] /. %, Element[{x, y}, Reals]] // Union // Normal

(*
{{a -> ConditionalExpression[y^2, y > 0],  b -> ConditionalExpression[x^2 + y^2, y > 0]}, 
{a -> ConditionalExpression[x^2 + y^2, y > 0],  b -> ConditionalExpression[y^2, y > 0]}}

{y + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]}
*)
```